# $\imath ^{p}$ is a normed space

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

In my notes a given example is as suggested:

> Example:
>
> On the space of sequence $\imath$ we define , for $1\leq p< \infty
> \left \| x \right \|_{p}:=\left ( \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left | x_{i} \right |^{p} \right )^{\frac{1}{p}}$
>   and $\imath ^{p}:=\left \{ x \in \imath : \left \| x \right \|_{p}<\infty \right \}$
>   is a normed space.

Clearly, $\imath$ is a vector space.

Recall that for any vector space V and a norm $**\left \| \cdot  \right \|, \left ( V,\left \| \cdot  \right \| \right )**$ is a normed space.

How should I write the normed space in the bold notation?

Is $\left ( l,\left \| x \right \|_{p} \right )$ correct?
What about writing $\imath ^{p}$ is a normed space in notation $\left ( V,\left \| \cdot  \right \| \right )$?
[image]
Secondly, how do I show that $\imath ^{p}$ is a normed space?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notation: There's rarely a false but I like the one of the book you quoted.

To show $l^p$ is a normed space you have to show the axioms of a norm.
See here
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)

The difficult one is the triangle inequality and you need Minkowski there; if more info needed answer^^

Btw these spaces are called $l^P$-spaces.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand quite a bit of stuffs that is going on in the OP which I hope you could perhaps shed some light.
$\imath ^{p}$ is a normed space as claimed. I know that I have to show the norm axiom. But when we say$ \imath ^{p}$ is a normed space, what is the vector space here and what is the norm here?

Comment: OK lets do it then

Comment: (1.absolute homogeneity:) Let $a \in R, x \in V$ and see:$$||ax||_p= (\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |ax_i|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}} = (\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |a|^p |x_i|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}} = |a|(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |x_i|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$ i only used the homogeneity of $|.|$.

Comment: (2.definiteness) Let $x=0 \in V$ then $$ ||0||_p= (\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |0|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}} = 0$$ and the other way round: let $||x||_p=0 $ then $$0=(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |x_i|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$ and therefore $$0=(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |x_i|^p)$$ . Now assume at least one of the $x_i$ isn't $0$ and let $x_j$ be this guy then you would have $$0=(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |x_i|^p) =(\sum_{i=1,i\not=j}^{\infty} |x_i|^p) + |x_j| > 0$$, because $ |x_j|>0$ and $(\sum_{i=1,i\not=j}^{\infty} |x_i|^p)\geq 0$ cause of definitness of $|.|$

Comment: That's a contradiction and you know all $x_i=0$ and therefore $x=0$ ok so far?

Comment: Now the difficult part: (3. triangle inequality) first: may I use minkowski inequality?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality because that's exact the same here( for the proof you can substitute the integrals by sums f.e.)

Comment: One thing should by mentioned; these sums are always infinite (called series as you know maybe) and you have always to say, if the series converges you have the following... ok?

Comment: Yes, you could use the minkowski inequality.

Comment: Hey @Mathematicing is this a question or is it clear now?